# Algorithm to separate circles to reduce collision the maximum between them

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I'll try to do my best to explain this.

I have X circles (from 2 to 4) which can move around smaller pivot circles. The pivot circles are fixed and cannot be moved once they are in the "field". Pivot circles are never created colliding with other pivot circles. Something like this:

[image]

Red are pivot circles (fixed) and orange are the normal circles (displace without exiting the pivot circles).

Now if I put two pivot circles near, the algorithm should do something like this:

[image]

This is pretty easy to achieve. Detect colliding circles and displace them the needed amount. Because red circles never collide, the orange circles are never going to break the "do not exit the pivot circle" rule.

The problem comes when 3 or more circles come into play. Because they cannot exit the pivot circle zone, so there should be some vertical/horizontal movement, like this:

[image]

I think this is the least colliding I can achieve when 4 pivots are next to the other. I created this manually but I'd like to know if there's already an algorithm to detect this efficiently without making a lot of detections/passes to achieve the least colliding factor, as I don't like everything that I'm thinking on.

The best I can think of is to simply do a loop where I detect all circle collisions, then displace the circles the amount needed for them to avoid the collisions the maximum possible, then repeat the loop, and repeat until I find that the "collision factor" is not reduced anymore for the next X steps. To make the circles go "up" and "down" I can try to create a bit of noise each time, and the algorithm will do the rest to move the circles up and down. Also, instead of noise I can try to detect if they are colliding "horizontally" or "vertically" and add a bit of horizontal/vertical movement when a circle with 2 or more collisions has a perfect horizontal/vertical collision.

I don't like this much actually, so well, here I am hehe.

I can't think of something, but I'm pretty sure that there's something that can be calculated with one step, instead of looping the same step multiple times, but I'm really stuck and nothing comes out of my head.

Comment: Do all the circles have the same fixed radius? What about the pivots?

Comment: "Reduce collision the maximum between them".  Do you want to reduce the area of all overlapped regions? Or just the number of pairs of colliding circles? Or what?

Comment: I don't know if it interests you, but I think it is easier to find a pivot configuration that has a 0 overlap solution.

Comment: This looks a lot like the problem of placing labels on a map.  For some variants, when a totally overlap-free solution exists, it can be found in polynomial time using 2SAT; if no totally overlap-free solution exists, you may need to go to MAX-2SAT, which is NP-hard, but can actually be solved to within about 6% of optimal in poly-time.

Comment: @orlp Yep. Exactly the circles have double the radius of the pivots. All the pivots have the same size.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Reduce the area. I prefer to have 2 small overlaps rather than 1 big overlap, like the third image shows.

Comment: @VinceThank you, but I can't control pivot locations. I only can control that they do not overlap when placed.

Comment: @j_random_hacker perfect, thank you. Going to research for that ^^

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker To add, I think that we can transform this problem a bit and see that it is harder than point labeling 4-location placement model, which known to be NP-hard. Also see [Wikipedia on labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_label_placement).

Comment: @Discretelizard: Looks like you're right.  I think 2SAT could still be useful as a heuristic that's less greedy than just picking random positions for orange circles until you get stuck, then repeating the whole exercise until you get lucky: Pick *two* random positions for each orange circle, solve 2SAT, repeat until lucky ;)

Comment: One fairly obvious rule that will help if your problems are mostly "sparse": Put an edge between every pair of red circles whose orange circles could possibly overlap (a simple distance test).  Each connected component in the resulting graph can be solved independently.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help. I thout that there sould be one "single step" method, but all I see is bruteforcing, so I thought abount using a physics engine, so the problem is solved easily. This is the result: https://vgy.me/s58iWP.gif

Comment: Now I have to simply "fast-forward" it to compute multiple steps instantly and this is the result (each flick is one run): https://vgy.me/MpDb2B.gif

Comment: And as the last step, after this, I just have to displace the circles to be next to the edge of the pivots (working on this, but I just want to displace the red lines amount): https://i.imgur.com/8kjiOiQ.png

Comment: And with this I guess that I get the result that I want. I do not post an answer with all this because I'm not sure that this is what I want exactly, but don't looks bad actually. By the way I'm sure that all those bruteforce algorithms have better performance, but the performance of this is not that bad for the application I want so I'm going forward with it.

Comment: If you have found some solution that serves your needs, feel free to self-answer your question with an overview of your solution. This can help others that have similar problems as yours.

Comment: @Discretelizard Yep, nice. I'm goijng to finish it first before, just in case.

Comment: Have a look at *areas closer to one from a set points than to any other*: [Voronoi diagrams](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram).

Comment: @greybeard That's pretty cool actually. Will also avoid the small circle overlaps. Going to test some things. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to brute force it, this is a constrained optimization problem where the quantity you're minimizing is the overlap area, the variables are the x and y coordinates of each circle's center, and the constraints are that each center lies within a red circle.

Depending on how you want to count areas inside three or more circles, the formula for the overlap arra can be reasonably simple or a huge mess that gets worse with the number of circles.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. As I see that I have to bruteforce it, I thought of using a physics engine.

Comment: A constrained optimizer would get you the actual optimum, whereas some kind of physics based simulation wouldn't come with any such guarantee (unless you could prove that it works out the same for this problem for some special reason.)

Comment: By the way, what are you actually using this for?  Maybe you could solve a similar but different problem that's easier to solve but just as good for your purposes.

Comment: I have a board game where people move tokens around by tapping on them. Tokens (pivot points) never overlap other tokens, but can sit next to each other in different positions. The problem is that for mobile phones tokens are a bit small because of the amount of cells the board has, and the tokens can't be bigger than a cell width/height, and I don't want to enable pinch-zoom for my app. I thought about adding bigger "touch areas" for each token, but when tokens sit next to each other, touch areas don't work as expected because they overlap, so I though into displacing them, and here I am :-)

Comment: I don't get the point of a constrained optimizer. I'm not an "algorithms guy", but more a programmer guy. I ended up with this which works pretty well, and can be optimized a bit more actually: http://jsfiddle.net/26Ls0nvz/3/ but if you can show me more about that "optimum" thing you talk about, that would be awesome, as depending on a physics engine for this is a bit weird. Like killing flies with a cannon.

Comment: Try taking a voronoi decomposition with respect to the centers of the tokens.  Since the cells.can extend pretty far in regions where there are no tokens, when someone clicks inside the cell corresponding to a token check if they're close enough to the token before initiating the drag.  This gives each token the largest possible hit box and is straightforward to calculate.

Comment: The problem is that tokens are exactly the same width/height as the cell. Look at this: https://i.imgur.com/Qxsvp91.png so "tap cell detection" is a problem here.